# How can I programmatically set the default export path?

Tags: features

In Drupal 7, you can set the default export path for the [features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) module by setting the variable 'features_default_export_path':

```
variable_set('features_default_export_path', 'sites/all/modules/custom/features');
```

What is the equivalent in Drupal 8? Can the export path be set in the features.settings configuration object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like configuration for the features module is managed in the features.settings configuration object. This settings can be viewed and change via drush.

Viewing the features configuration directory:

```
drush cget features.settings
```

Setting the features configuration directory:

```
drush cset features.settings export.folder "custom/features"
```